# How to convert char[] to LPCTSTR?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have function Write with argument `LPCTSTR` path for winapi function `CreateFile`. How I can convert `char[]` to `LPCTSTR` and pass it to func?
P.S. I"ve already seen other themes and there is nothing useful

Comment: I suggest using the wide versions of those, not the `T*` versions, unless you plan to support extremely old versions of Windows.

Comment: [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b073d1cb-cb16-4956-b3ef-9021265f8efe/convert-char-to-lpctstr] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LPCTSTR` is a macro for `const TCHAR*`.  `TCHAR` will either be `char` or `wchar_t` (`unsigned short` in older versions of Visual C++) depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined.  You have a few options:

1. Use a `TCHAR[]` instead of `char[]`.  You can use the `TEXT` and `T` macros do that that for string literals.
2. Undefine `UNICODE` and build your project without wide character support.  (Conversely, you could leave it defined and use wide character sets instead of ANSI).
3. Do a conversion from a single byte to multi-byte character set.  You can find more information regarding the character sets and the conversion functions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/544tbtd1.aspx).

A forth option is to use the `CreateFileW` (or `CreateFileA` depending on your desires) instead of the `CreateFile` (which will map to either of the previously mentioned functions depending on the `UNICODE` pre-processor flag).

Comment: It's either `char` or `wchar_t`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan And `wchar_t` is a typedef for `unsigned short` (though, if memory serves, they added it as a primitive type in C++11 - [which they did](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dh8che7s.aspx)).

Comment: @AlanStokes If you wanted to be able to compile both with and without the `UNICODE` preprocessor.  If your application does not require globalization, for example.

Comment: @Zac So you'd suggest using unsigned short in place of wchar_t?

Comment: @Zac You only use TCHAR if you need to run your program on Windows 98

Comment: But +1 for you. Sadly the asker accepted the wrong answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Not at all.  I was mentioning it so the OP would understand the difference between the types when the `UNICODE` directive is (and is not) included.  The "conversion" is different when it is not included (no conversion necessary) than when it is.  And you would be surprised how many times I've had to avoid using wide character sets for production code ... the US government is notorious for trying to keep its computer systems forever ...

Answer (score 2):

Call `CreateFileA` (explicitly asking for the narrow character version) and just pass your `char []` directly to it, no casts needed.

Comment: @prozac Now your program is stuck with lame ANSI character sets. Why would you want to inflict that on yourself. The rest of us spent years learning to despise ANSI. It's 2014. Not everyone in the world speaks English.

Comment: @David That choice is already made with the use of `char`. (Well, it could be UTF8, but Windows makes that very painful.)

Comment: The user doesn't have to use char